# How Do i make JSON Get from input text and find it? ( explained in topic)

Tags: html, json

So i'm trying to get specific string from api that uses json.
Heres what im trying to do:
HERES THE IDEA IM TRYING TO DO : https://us.mc-api.net/example/uuid
So i want the mayed505 replaced by the name in the text box and submits when the button is clicked ( this is minecraft api which you replace PLAYERNAME and put someones name and all the information will appear.) https://us.mc-api.net/v3/uuid/PLAYERNAME

```js
var getJSON = function(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if (status == 200) {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      } else {
        reject(status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  });
};

getJSON('https://us.mc-api.net/v3/uuid/mayed505').then(function(data) {

//                                     ^^^^^^^^ I want that be replaced with the input text in HTML like:
  //https://us.mc-api.net/v3/uuid/INPUT FROM TXT BAR
     

    //alert('Your Json result is:  ' + data.full_uuid); //you can comment this, i used it to debug

    full_uuid.innerText = data.full_uuid; //display the result in an HTML element
    }, function(status) { //error detection....
  alert('Something went wrong.');
});
```

```html
<div id="full_uuid" style="color:red"></div>
<input id="playerName" type="hidden name" value="Username">
<input data-inline="true" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Submit to get UUID">
```

Comment: Is your questions how to get data from a field? [That question exists many times over already.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-get-input-text-value)

Comment: type="hidden name"?
 
store the url in variable. on click of the button create the url with the username and make the request

var username = document.getElementById('playerName').value; 
var url = 'https://us.mc-api.net/v3/uuid/'+username;

getJSON(url).then(function(data) {.................

Comment: @MatthewHerbst yes. and replace mayed505 with the name in text input

Comment: @iamkdev can u explain more? i cant see the code.

Comment: @iamkdev here i tried doesn't work either can u make me a jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/m600yt3a/  and heres the api im trying to use https://us.mc-api.net/example/uuid

Comment: I change few thing like the 
<input id="playerName" type="hidden name" value="Username">
Check my answer if thats works for you

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```js
var getJSON = function(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if (status == 200) {
        resolve(xhr.response);
        alert(JSON.stringify(xhr.response));
      } else {
        reject(status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  });
};

getJSON(url).then(function(data) {

//                                     ^^^^^^^^ I want that be replaced with the input text in HTML like:
  //https://us.mc-api.net/v3/uuid/INPUT FROM TXT BAR
     

    //alert('Your Json result is:  ' + data.full_uuid); //you can comment this, i used it to debug

    full_uuid.innerText = data.full_uuid; //display the result in an HTML element
    }, function(status) { //error detection....
  alert('Something went wrong.');
});

function fetchData(){
  var username = document.getElementById('playerName').value; 
  var url = 'https://us.mc-api.net/v3/uuid/'+username; 
  getJSON(url);
}
```

```html
<div id="full_uuid" style="color:red"></div>
<input id="playerName" type="text" name="username" value="mayed505">
<input data-inline="true" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Submit to get UUID" onclick="fetchData()">
```

Comment: Check the console for respond 
I got this 


{"full_uuid":"ab77ddd0-898b-453c-8378-5cfdd8dcb51f","source":"cache","query":"mayed505","name":"Mayed505","took":0,"uuid":"ab77ddd0898b453c83785cfdd8dcb51f"}

Comment: I checked console it says: (index):92 Uncaught ReferenceError: fetchData is not defined

Comment: Man you have to learn basics .... What you are accepting if you have done nothing with the respond.

Check the respond for the request

Comment: Well the problem im 13...... im simple app maker https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mayed.minecraftskinsearch                 i made this app and im trying to improve it since i dont know json verywell

Comment: is it possible? to get full_uuid like my old code? everything works fine i guess i have to learn json

Comment: In your old code you have not done anything to the button onClick or onSubmit  event. And also the url need the username to get the data. So, you have to make that before getJSON execute.